# Typescript : method in var can't call another method?

Tags: typescript

I want to run a random function. My code looks like this :

```
module A {

    ...

    export function foo(): number {

        let b = new B();

        let possibleFunctions = [
            b.possibleFunction1,
            b.possibleFunction2
        ];
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        possibleFunctions[index](_var_);
    }

    class B {

        public usefulFunction() {
            console.log("bbbb");
            ...
        }

        public possibleFunction1() {
            ...
            console.log("aaaa");
            this.usefulFunction(); // <-- IS NOT CALLED
            console.log("cccc");
        }

        public possibleFunction2() {
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

The output seems to be only `aaaa` and the function `usefulFunciton` is never called (it makes an error).

If I replace

```
possibleFunctions[index](_var_);
```

by

```
possibleFunction1(_var_);
```

everything works just fine.

So I was curious to know:

***1.***  Are my observations correct?

***2.***  Why so? Is the function deep-copied or something?

***3.***  What's the correct way to do it?

Thank you !

Comment: What exactly is '_var_' you did not defined it anywhere, and why are you passing a parameter at the function call, while the function does not accept any parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by weirdness of `this` keyword in javascript. Its behavior different than in any other common language. Simply put you get different objects as `this` depending on how you are calling the function. One way to overcome the issue is calling function like this:

```
 possibleFunctions[index].apply(b, argsArray);
```

The first parameter of `apply` is the object that will be available as `this`, second is and array of arguments to your function.

---

As @Ced suggested other way is to `bind` your function to correct this.

```
let possibleFunctions = [
       b.possibleFunction1.bind(b), 
       b.possibleFunction2.bind(b) 
    ];
```

This forces the `this` to be `b` regardless of the way you call the function.

Comment: Another approach is to use
let possibleFunctions = [
            b.possibleFunction1.bind(b),
            b.possibleFunction2.bind(b)
];
which is a little bit more straight forward in my opinion.

Comment: Oh. I get it. Thanks for the explanation!
May I ask: what if the class was not in the module but imported from another file? Would it work too?